# Create a drop down list of Users in Rails with two attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dictionary, attributes, helper

I'm trying to display a drop down list of Users with a specific value in one of the User table columns. I'm doing that with the following code:

```
def vet_all_select_options
    User.where(:department_id => '2').map{ |user| [user.name, user.name] }
end
```

I need to get the `user.name` and the `user.qualifications` into the remote forms field. The above code is in the User helper and works well, I'm just unsure on how to have an additional attribute.

Something like the following is what I would like to do but it doesn't work:

```
def vet_all_select_options
    User.where(:department_id => '2').map{ |user| [user.name, user.name user.qualifications] }
end
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `def vet_all_select_options
    User.where(:department_id => '2').map{ |user| [user.name, "#{user.name} #{user.qualifications}"] }
end`